# Textbox stretch inside MenuItem WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, menuitem

I'm trying to create a `MenuItem` which contains both a `Label` and a `TextBox`. I would like the `Textbox`'s width to stretch to the entire width of the column.

For some reason, the `TextBox`'s width is always small (probably at the length of the text).

Here's my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridLinesRatioGrid" Width="Auto">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Label x:Name="GridLinesRatioLabel" Content="Grid Lines Ratio" Foreground="DarkRed" Focusable="False" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
     <TextBox x:Name="GridLinesRatioTextBox" Foreground="DarkRed" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I tried your piece of code and its working fine. TextBox is streching to the column width. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: For some reason mine isn't stretching, using the exact same piece of code. The length of my TextBox is aligned with the length of it's `Text` property.

Comment: Do you mean there is a lot of gap between your label and textbox?

Comment: Nope, it's like instead of having the `Label` area's width take 80% of the entire area, and 20% for the `Textbox`, the `Label` takes what it needs (around 70%), the `Texbox` is empty so it is very small, taking about 5% and the rest (about 25% of the entire line) is empty. The length of the `Textbox` is less that one character.

Comment: The piece of code looks fine, may be the parent element is changing some property. Can you edit the post with parent element also that is from MenuItem.